# Reverse proxy an http:// domain to a GitHub Pages URL

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a URL, `http://example.com`, that I would like to use to serve content from my GitHub Pages site at `https://myusername.github.io/mysite/` via a reverse proxy in Apache. This is both as a temporary workaround until I update `example.com`'s DNS setting to point to GitHub Pages, as well as to teach myself how reverse proxies work.

I have my Apache config like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    ProxyPass "/" "https://myusername.github.io/mysite/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to go to "example.com", I get "The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server."

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so, what should I be changing?

I'm using Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove the line:

`SSLEngine On`

It enables HTTPS on your port 80... but you don't provide an SSL certificate (...and HTTPS uses port 443).
You should also add the line:

`ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://myusername.github.io/mysite/"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement a reverse proxy yourself, since Github allows you to specify a custom domain

[https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-
pages-site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)

Answer (score 0):

The following config works perfectly on reverse proxy github pages

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName custom-domain
        ServerAdmin encycode@gmail.com

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        RequestHeader set Host "myusername.github.io"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
        RequestHeader set Origin "myusername.github.io"

        ProxyPass / https://myusername.github.io/mysite/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://myusername.github.io/mysite/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Make sure you replace myusername with your github username, mysite with your github repo name and custom-domain with your custom url**